# Cannot create Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-composer, terraform-provider-gcp

I am getting the error below while provisioning Composer via terraform.

> Error: Error waiting to create Environment: Error waiting to create Environment: Error waiting for Creating Environment: error while retrieving operation: Get "https://composer.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/aayush-terraform/locations/us-central1/operations/ee459492-abb0-4646-893e-09d112219d79?alt=json&prettyPrint=false": write tcp 10.227.112.165:63811->142.251.12.95:443: write: broken pipe. An initial environment was or is still being created, and clean up failed with error: Getting creation operation state failed while waiting for environment to finish creating, but environment seems to still be in 'CREATING' state. Wait for operation to finish and either manually delete environment or import "projects/aayush-terraform/locations/us-central1/environments/example-composer-env" into your state.

Below is the code snippet:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
  }
}

variable "gcp_region" {
  type        = string
  description = "Region to use for GCP provider"
  default     = "us-central1"
}

variable "gcp_project" {
  type        = string
  description = "Project to use for this config"
  default     = "aayush-terraform"
}

provider "google" {
  region  = var.gcp_region
  project = var.gcp_project
}

resource "google_service_account" "test" {
  account_id   = "composer-env-account"
  display_name = "Test Service Account for Composer Environment"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "composer-worker" {
  role   = "roles/composer.worker"
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.test.email}"
}

resource "google_compute_network" "test" {
  name                    = "composer-test-network"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "test" {
  name          = "composer-test-subnetwork"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.2.0.0/16"
  region        = "us-central1"
  network       = google_compute_network.test.id
}

resource "google_composer_environment" "test" {
  name   = "example-composer-env"
  region = "us-central1"
  config {
    node_count = 3

    node_config {
      zone         = "us-central1-a"
      machine_type = "n1-standard-1"

      network    = google_compute_network.test.id
      subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.test.id

      service_account = google_service_account.test.name
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: Composer is getting created even after this error is being thrown and I am provisioning this composer via service account which has been given owner access.

Comment: Just showing us an error message is not a question. Please add more details.

Comment: added the necessary details. Not sure if this error might be a problem or not.

Comment: Hi Drive Upload, Can you add the following roles to your service account as mentioned in the [document](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-composer#service-account)?Provide Cloud Composer v2 API Service Agent Extension role to the service account and check your [access controls](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/access-control#composer-sa). Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it by giving the **"composer.operations.get
"** permission to the service account which is provisioning the Composer.
This permission is part of the **Composer Administrator** role.
To prevent future operations like updates or deletion through Terraform, I think it's better to use the role rather than a single permission.
Or if you want to make some least privileges work, you can first use the role, then removing permissions you think you won't need and test your terraform code.